# By convention, does 'make install' copy header files to /usr/include?

Tags: linux, makefile

I do `make install` on a certain library I should be using. I see `.so` files are copied to `/usr/lib`, but `.h` are not copied to `/usr/include`. Is that right by convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, files should be copied to

```
headers  -> $DESTDIR$PREFIX/include
libs     -> $DESTDIR$PREFIX/lib
binaries -> $DESTDIR$PREFIX/bin
```

where `DESTDIR` variable is empty by default. And `PREFIX` is usually set to something like `/usr` or `/usr/local`, depending on your intentions. Usually, software which is managed by your system's native package manager is installed to `/usr`, while software which is not supposed to be managed by operating system's package manager usually goes to `/usr/local`. So, in your case it *should* go to `/usr/local`, but what your `makefile` actually does is under question.

Comment: Awesome answer! Learned a ton. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "default" for Makefiles and install pathes. But there is a more or less common file system hierarchy which can be found e.g. here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

From a user perspective I expect that any manual installation will go to /usr/local/...

/usr/... is managed by the distribution and as this it is dangerous to put own files there by default. Maybe your file will conflict with others from the distribution management.

There are a lot of conventions around with different linux ditributions and there is a "standard" which gives more rules also for file system organization:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

So you can check your requirements against this standards.

Answer (score 1):

Another place they may be installed is the `/opt` directory.

```
/opt/include/*.h
/opt/lib/lib*.so
/opt/bin/*
```

In general the top-level directories (`/bin`, `/lib`) are for the system commands and libraries (eg. `/bin/bash`). The `/usr` directories for applications software and libraries (eg. `/usr/bin/libreoffice`). The `/opt` directories for in-house software. Also, if an app needs an older library, it may be store in `/opt` so it won't interfere with other apps.